# Current sense amplifier for overcurrent protection

Tags: mosfet, simulation, protection, pspice

I'm trying to compare the use of a current sense amplifier with a sense resistor for overcurrent protection of SiC MOSFET. Here is my schematic using  [INA210](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina210.pdf?ts=1602089473746&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FINA210) current sense amplifier, UCC21732-Q1, and SCT3160KL MOSFET.
[image: Schematic]

And this is the simulation output:-

[image: output]

How can the /FLT pin go low before OC sends the signal? Or should I see the delay time right from when OC pin starts to go high?